# MYSQL query and pulling second column of data based on first column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

Hopefully I can explain this well.  I'm trying to pull in my database the max points, assists, and rebounds from one column and then based on that number, grab the game number (gid) where each of those numbers came from.  I started it with something simple, thinking I could get it, but the gid it grabs is just the first id for that particular season, not for the right game in any case.

```
SELECT gid, sid, max(points), max(assists), max(rebounds) 
FROM game_stats_lakers 
WHERE playerid = 2 
GROUP By gid
```

I want to get the gid (which is the game id) for the max points, assists, and rebounds which most likely will be different for each. I can't seem to figure out how to pull any gid correctly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So what is `sid`? What behavior do you want with duplicate maximiums? Let the sample data provided exemplify this. Which mysql version?

Comment: There are a lot of questions like this in SO; like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365937/get-row-with-maxcolumn . Sure it's not exactly same situation as yours but [I bet you can get the idea once you do your research](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getting+max+value+with+correct+id)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
(select gsl.*
 from game_stats_lakers gsl
 where playerid = 2 
 order by gsl.points desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select gsl.*
 from game_stats_lakers gsl
 where playerid = 2 
 order by gsl.assists desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select gsl.*
 from game_stats_lakers gsl
 where playerid = 2 
 order by gsl.rebounds desc
 limit 1
) ;
```

Comment: It looks like that's very close, but it needs to be for the playerid of 2.  That's what differentiates which player it is.

Comment: Actually I think I got it, that's it, perfect. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Last question and I think I'm all set.  How do I set it so it grabs those numbers, one for each season.  So playerid 2, plays 10 seasons, I want to show the highs in points, assists, and rebounds for each of those seasons.  Sid is the code for each season.  Thank you again!

Comment: @BrettNorton . . . That would be a different question.  I would suggest that you ask a new question with sample data and desired results.